# Why is the object not selected?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I wrote this code-

```
         ViewData ["ProductId"] = new SelectList (_context.Set <Product> (), "Id", "ProductsTitle", _context.Product.Where (m => m.Id == productId) .FirstOrDefault ());
```

But the selected object (_context.Product.Where (m => m.Id == productId) .FirstOrDefault ()) is not selected on the page.

How can I fix the code to make it work?

Regards

Comment: If you are using a select tag helper, the selected value is taken from the asp-for, not the selectlist: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/select-tag-helper#setting-selected-item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select a specific object, you only need to pass in the `id`.

```
 ViewData ["ProductId"] = new SelectList (_context.Set <Product> (), "Id", "ProductsTitle", productId);
```

View:

```
<select asp-for="ProductId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProductId"></select>
```